# Can you use a power drill with the exchangeable screwdriver bits on a manual screwdriver?

Tags: drill, powertools, screwdriver

If not, what is the difference between a screwdriver bit that is designed for a power tool versus the ones that come with a multi-bit screw driver set like these: http://www.homedepot.com/b/Tools-Hardware-Hand-Tools-Screwdrivers-Nut-Drivers-Screwdrivers-Multi-Bit-Screwdrivers/N-5yc1vZc98m ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Screwdriver bits are generally considered consumable. Regardless of the brand, they eventually break/wear out. Hardware stores sell them in packs of 5-10 for exactly that reason. I wouldn't put too much stock in what kind of tool the bit originally came with.

The only exception is if you're using an impact driver you might want to be a little more picky. Impact drivers (or impact wrenches) put a **huge** amount of torque on the bit, and a cheap one could fail catastrophically. There are special "impact driver bit sets" you can buy that advertise high torque strength.

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal world the power tool tips would be stronger. In reality the quality of the tips is anybody's guess. In general those with a large tool company's name on the package are better quality. But I have bought brand name sets that broke the first time they were used. I have had the kind you buy at discount stores work well. As with any power tool you should have eye protection. When these tips fail they tend to send small chips in any direction.